# Catch run time exception in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have the following code structure:

```
begin
  <block of code>
rescue Exception => e
  <block of code>
end
```

This cannot catch run time errors, and Chef run fails.

Is there any way to catch exception during run time in Chef?

Comment: If the error occurred in the first one of your `<block of code>`, then that should be captured. If you indeed have an error that is not captured, then that must be from the second one of your `<block of code>`, and there is no way to save that unless you put another `begin`...`rescue` block in there.

Comment: @sawa - second   <block of code> have some log() only nothing else. In the first   <block of code>, have added chef resources like 'execute', which is failing and not able catch by rescue

Answer (score 1):

This will only catch exceptions at compile time, not converge time. Chef is inherently asynchronous thanks to our two-pass loading model. You can read more about it at https://coderanger.net/two-pass/. In general the only option is the `ignore_errors` property, though that will still show a nasty error trace, it just won't abort the run when a resource errors. More specifically you would need to say what kind of code you're talking about. You probably want to use guard conditions (`not_if`/`only_if`) to avoid converging the resource if something is wrong and it will fail.